# Java Generics Inheritance

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have 2 different types of data managers, one inherits the other and both rely on 1 base data class and looks like this:

```
public abstract class BaseDataType {
    ...
}

public class BaseManager<DataType extends BaseDataType> implements ListModel{
    ...
    public final DataType get(index i){
        return dataList.get(i);
    }
    ...
}

public class BaseSQLManager<DataType extends BaseDataType, Adapter extends SQLAdapter>
    extends BaseManager<DataType>{
    ...
}
```

My understanding that using `BaseSQLManager m =new BaseSQLManager<Property, PropertSQLAdapter>();` would allow me to use `Property p = m.get(i);` however I am informed that the get method returns BaseDataType.

I'm sure I'm missing something small here and I can't figure it out. An explanation of why this doesn't work would really help. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
BaseSQLManager m =new BaseSQLManager<Property, PropertSQLAdapter>();
```

Yes, you are missing the type parameter in the variable declaration, i.e. the type of `m` does not constrain the type parameter, which is why get() is only known to return something that extends BaseDataType. It should be:

```
BaseSQLManager<Property, PropertSQLAdapter> m 
    = new BaseSQLManager<Property, PropertSQLAdapter>();
```

Comment: How embarrassing, of course it is, been looking at it so long that I can't see the wood from the trees. Thank you very much, I'll accept your answer as soon as it will let me